# Cannot render text filtered with trans in twig template using Sandbox Security Policy

Tags: symfony, internationalization, twig, twig-extension

I am a little bit confused. First of all, look at my code, I guess.

```
public function renderTemplate($templateType, $data)
{
    $layoutName = "$templateType.layout.html.twig";
    $policy = new \Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy(
        ['if', 'for', 'block', 'set', 'extends'],
        ['escape', 'format', 'dateformat', 'trans', 'raw', 'striptags'],
        self::$allowedMethods,
        self::$allowedProperties,
        ['gettext']
    );
    $sandboxExt = new \Twig_Extension_Sandbox($policy);
    $intlExt = new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl();
    $i18nExt = new \Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n();
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . "/../Resources/views/Something/", "__main__"));
    $sandboxExt->enableSandbox();
    $twig->addExtension($sandboxExt);
    $twig->addExtension($intlExt);
    $twig->addExtension($i18nExt);
    try {
        $result = $twig->render($layoutName, $data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($e);die();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Here it is the template I want to render

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ entity.id }}{% endblock %}
{% block bodyTitle %}
    {{ entity.id }} {{ 'translation_key.created_at'|trans({}, 'entities', locale) }} {{ entity.createdAt|dateformat(null, locale) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here, as you can see, I want to render a template according to its type. **The problem is:** half of the template renders just fine, and then, when it tries to render the translated string, it throws an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gettext() in /home/dev/vhosts/my-project/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code on line 69
```

I checked if this function existed right before trying to call render method, and it was really undefined. Basically, I have 2 questions here:

**Question 1**
How does it work in other parts of my project, but not in this specific handler? See "Important update" below.

**Question 2**
Can I solve my problem in another way? For example, without using Sandbox or using Sandbox with some kind of a flag "everythingAllowed=true"?

**ATTENTION! IMPORTANT UPDATE**
Previously, I misunderstood my own question. I thought the error was thrown while rendering the variable, but I re-checked the situation (When Alain Tiemblo asked me for twig template code here in comments) and now 100% sure it's thrown while trying to translate smth. Also, I have translations all over my project, and it works just fine, but in this specific situation it's not. I think it worth to mention, that I also tried to render the template without using Sandbox. I tried to render it directly from Twig Engine like this

```
return $this->templating->render($layoutName, $data);
//$this->templating is injected in the constructor via services.yml like this
//arguments:
//  - "@templating"
```

The result - not properly translated text. When I dumped "locale" - I got one specific language, but the text was translated in another. But at least using this method - I didn't get any errors.. Can anybody clarify this for me? Because I really don't understand how the Intl/i18n extension works and why it doesn't want to work in Sandbox or not in Sanbox?

P.S. My guess, why it doesn't work directly from Twig Engine - probably I should inject not like "@templating" or it injects just right, but the Intl or I18n extensions are not enabled? How to enable. And I have no clues why it doesn't work with Sandbox

Comment: Can you give the Twig code? I don't really get the point. Thanks :)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo Yes, I can. I added it. But please, look at the "Attention! Important Update" section . Previously, I asked my question in the wrong way. Basically it's the problem of using i18n extension or intl extension I guess.

Comment: Did you get it to work ?